# How to understand "Affine Connectives" in Logic

Tags: logic

I am looking into functional completeness and I am trying to understand the rules for Emil Post's proof. One of the rules is the following:

The **affine connectives**, such that each connected variable either always or never affects the truth value these connectives return, e.g. $\top$, $\bot$, $\lnot$, $\oplus$, $\leftrightarrow$.

I am having difficulty showing that these connectives are indeed affine.

Perhaps I am just overthinking this. Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: $\bot$ and $\top$ are obvious: they are constant (in terms of truth value). Also $\lnot$ is: changing the truth value of $p$ always affects the truth value of $\lnot p$.

Comment: For $\leftrightarrow$, compare it with $\lor$. If $p$ is true, changing the truth value of $q$ does not affect the truth value of $p \lor q$. The same for $p \land q$ is $p$ is false.